# Sonar qube while iterating in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using SonarQube to analyse the code. I have one method as below. Here i am checking not null condition already.

```
if (myentities == null && !myentities.Any())
{
    yield return default;
}
else
{
    foreach (var entity in myentities)
    {

        yield return entity.PrepareMyResponse();
    }
}
```

When I run SonarQube, it is pointing to the if condition and shows it as a bug. The message is "'myentities ' is null on at least one execution path.". How to solve this bug?

Comment: Nope, when i use count() i get a warning to use any for performance improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my experience is that it likes this better -- *combine* the checks and lose the `else`...

```cs
if (myentities?.Any() != true)
{
    yield return default;
}

foreach (var entity in myentities)
{

        yield return entity.PrepareMyResponse();
}
```

Comment: I do worry about this code, however. `yield return default` does indicate success and another iteration. `yield break` seems better here.

Comment: @Stand_Sure But here i am missing the null check..

Comment: @coder11b there is a null check. if `myentities` is `null`, then `myentities?.Any()` returns `null` and the `if` is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

What is the requirement to suspend the loop during the loop, if it is null, continue the loop without assigning a value

```
foreach (var entity in myentities)
{
      if (entity is null) continue;

      yield return entity.PrepareMyResponse();
}
```

Comment: get the same message

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).